# JavaScript array of objects to drop down list, only using certain properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects with two properties, `firstName` and `lastName`.  On a button click I would like to bind a drop down list to the page. Currently I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var obj1 =
                {
                    firstName: "john",
                    lastName: "smith"
                };
            var obj2 =
                {
                    firstName: "jane",
                    lastName: "doe"
                }
            var objArray = [];
            objArray.push(obj1);
            objArray.push(obj2);

            $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                makeDropDown(objArray);
            });
            function makeDropDown(array)
            {
                var $sel = $('<select/>');
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    for (var prop in array[i])
                    {
                        if(prop=='firstName')
                            var $option = $('<option/>').val(array[i][prop]).html(array[i][prop]).appendTo($sel);
                    }
                }
                $sel.appendTo('body');
            }
        });
```

This works, but I can't help but there's there's a better way of doing it.  I suppose I could make the function take another parameter (where firstName) is in the if statement, but that doesn't look right to me either.  What would be a good OO way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking an object-oriented approach will both reduce the amount of code and also make errors less likely. Let's start by adding a custom serialization method in your objects, to express how they should be rendered as `<option>`s. That way we don't have to write that code in every loop we render these, but rather the objects themselves can tell the rest of the code how to make them appear in select boxes.

Here's our first pass. We'll start with a naive approach, to demonstrate another benefit of being a little more object-oriented here, by putting our serialization method inline in each object.

```
   var obj1 =
   {
     firstName: "john",
     lastName: "smith",
     toOption: function () {
         return $('<option/>').val(this.firstName).html(this.firstName);
     }
   };

   var obj2 =
   {
     firstName: "jane",
     lastName: "doe"
     toOption: function () {
       return $('<option/>').val(this.firstName).html(this.firstName);
     }
   };

   var objArray = [];
   objArray.push(obj1);
   objArray.push(obj2);

   $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
   {
       makeDropDown(objArray);
   });

   function makeDropDown(array)
   {
            var $sel = $('<select/>');
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                array[i].toOption().appendTo($sel);
            }
            $sel.appendTo('body');
   }
```

Now our for-loop is easier to read and we can easily create these `<option>` tags elsewhere without having to copy and paste that code.

Yet this is still suboptimal, because we're writing that `toOption` function in every object. Since we find ourselves creating methods inside our objects, instead of inlining it repetitively, let's give ourselves the ability to create generic objects of this type. I'll call it a `Person`. As an added bonus, we can just create people inline now, instead of writing verbose JavaScript objects.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.toOption = function () {
         return $('<option/>').val(this.firstName).html(this.firstName);
    };
}

var objArray = [];
objArray.push(new Person('john', 'smith'));
objArray.push(new Person('jessica', 'jones'));

$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
   makeDropDown(objArray);
});

 function makeDropDown(array) {
     var $sel = $('<select/>');
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].toOption().appendTo($sel);
     }
     $sel.appendTo('body');
 }
```

This also means we can change the way our Persons render in one place, instead of all over our codebase.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably create a simple plugin.

```
$.fn.createDropDown = function(options){ //Take options
    var textField = options.textField, //get textfieldName from options
        valueField = options.valueField || textField; //if no valueField specified default to text field
     this.each(function(){
         $('<select/>').append($.map(options.source, function (ob) { //iterate through the source
            if(!ob[textField]) return true; //skip if atleast text field is not availabe in the object
            return $('<option/>', {  //create option and return
                value: ob[valueField],
                text: ob[textField]
            });
        })).appendTo(this); //append to each of the element in the selector
    });
    return this; //return it for chaining
}
```

and use it as

```
  var obj1 = {
        firstName: "john",
        lastName: "smith"
    };
    var obj2 = {
        firstName: "jane",
        lastName: "doe"
    }
    var objArray = [];
    objArray.push(obj1);
    objArray.push(obj2);

    var options = {  //set up options
       source:objArray,
       textField:'firstName',
       valueField:'firstName'
    }

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
       $('body').createDropDown(options); //Just invoke it with options
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CuzcD/)**

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't have to do much with OO, but with code reusability. Yes, a parameter for the propertyname is fine. You also might return the select element instead of appending it to the body, to provide greater flexibility.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var objArr = [
        {
           firstName: "john",
           lastName: "smith"
        },
        {
            firstName: "jane",
            lastName: "doe"
        }
    ];
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
        makeDropDown(objArray, "firstName").appendTo('body');
    });
    function makeDropDown(array, prop) {
        var $sel = $('<select/>');
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            $sel.append($('<option/>').val(array[i][prop]).text(array[i][prop]));
        return $sel;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, it looks like the person that wrote this knows what they were doing.  I like the idea of having the function return the drop down element, much nicer.